# Prism Modules - Why do I need them

Tags: prism

For a mid sized application that makes use of MEF catalogs is there really any advantage in my using Prism modules rather than just putting the different functionality into different class libraries. I just can't see why I would need to use Modules.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 1):

Modules are used when you want to perform initialization actions when the module is loaded. This can be for example the registration of views to regions using the Prism IRegionManager interface.

Answer (score 1):

What PVitt says is correct plus i would like to add to it.
Modules are always a good option for the scalability.
you can easily do future enhancements by having Regions,each region having some view associated with it and each view in different module.
when i say each view in different module it means you should find out which view is having some other view related to it and make a clubed view of these two views and have single module for these views. after all its your call.
for e.g.consider your application has a menu.Toolbar for each menu item is same i.e. having same functionality then you can have ToolbarView+Menuview inside "MenuView".MenuModule will have this  final MenuView.
So my opion is go with modular approach if you have any future enhancement or if your project is going to change time to time like new functionalities on user demand etc.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are a wonderful way to allow multiple development teams to develop at the same time. Also assist your to organize and maintain the Single Responsibility principle of SOLID principles in a Project level.

It helps your to have separation of concerns.